# How to create a shortcut on a shared drive that will open for multiple users

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I'm trying to migrate many of the commonly used documents for my organization to OneDrive. Mostly for versioning and multiuser editing support. Our current file system is on a shared network drive and I wanted to create a shortcut to replace the file that was migrated in-case anyone in the office has created some workflow to access the file in that location.

The issue is that to create a shortcut I use my username for my computer which is different from everyone else's.

How can I create a link that will open each individual's local copy (allowing OneDrive to sync them natively) while also only having one shortcut?

Comment: How are you creating the shortcut?  You can use the variable for the user profile, `%UserProfile%`, and simply add the path to the one drive directory from that.  What have you tried?

Comment: Ah! I had tried %User% but that didn't work, but knew there was some method of essentially creating a wildcard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use `%UserProfile%`